Rundeck group membership problems with OpenLDAP
I have followed the instructions on https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#case-insensitive-username to authenticate from my OpenLDAP server. The rundeck version is rundeck-5.4.0.20240618-1.noarch
In LDAP, I have an ou=Group,dc=mydomain,dc=com within which I have defined objects of class groupOfNames.
The /etc/rundeck/jaas-ldap.conf is:
ldap {
  com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule required
  debug="true"
  contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
  providerUrl="ldap://ldap.mydomain.com:389"
  bindDn="cn=binduser,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
  bindPassword="MyBindPassword"
  authenticationMethod="simple"
  forceBindingLogin="false"
  userBaseDn="ou=people,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
  userRdnAttribute="cn"
  userIdAttribute="cn"
  userPasswordAttribute="userPassword"
  userObjectClass="person"
  userLastNameAttribute="sn"
  userFirstNameAttribute="givenName"
  userEmailAttribute="mail"
  roleBaseDn="ou=group,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
  roleNameAttribute="cn"
  roleMemberAttribute="member"
  roleObjectClass="groupOfNames"
  cacheDurationMillis="300000"
  reportStatistics="true"
  timeoutRead="10000"
  timeoutConnect="20000"
  nestedGroups="false";
};

When attempting to login, I get the message:
[2024-07-24T15:28:39,748] INFO  jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule - Login attempts: 1, Hits: 0, Ratio: 0%.
[2024-07-24T15:28:39,753] DEBUG jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule - Found user?: true
[2024-07-24T15:28:39,753] DEBUG jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule - Searching for users with filter: '(&(objectClass={0})({1}={2}))' from base dn: ou=people,dc=mydomain,dc=com
[2024-07-24T15:28:39,754] DEBUG jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule - Found user?: true
[2024-07-24T15:28:39,755] DEBUG jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule - user cred is present: true
[2024-07-24T15:28:39,770] WARN  jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule - JettyCachingLdapLoginModule: User 'hussain' has no role membership; role query configuration may be incorrect


I have reproduced this:
[2024-07-30T19:13:01,098] INFO  jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule [qtp1120972967-46] - Login attempts: 1, Hits: 0, Ratio: 0%.
[2024-07-30T19:13:01,108] DEBUG jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule [qtp1120972967-46] - Found user?: true
[2024-07-30T19:13:01,108] DEBUG jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule [qtp1120972967-46] - Searching for users with filter: '(&(objectClass={0})({1}={2}))' from base dn: ou=users,dc=cse,dc=com
[2024-07-30T19:13:01,114] DEBUG jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule [qtp1120972967-46] - Found user?: true
[2024-07-30T19:13:01,115] DEBUG jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule [qtp1120972967-46] - user cred is present: true
[2024-07-30T19:13:01,145] WARN  jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule [qtp1120972967-46] - JettyCachingLdapLoginModule: User 'testuser' has no role membership; role query configuration may be incorrect

What is the actual question here? the message is a warning saying that that user doesn't have a role in your ldap configuration.
Here is an example of what I added in my ldap config to get a role for testuser user:
dn: cn=testuser,ou=roles,dc=cse,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: cn=testuser,ou=users,dc=cse,dc=com
cn: testuser


Looking at the slapd log, I see that the rundeck configuration is the problem as I see queries for group names themselves within the group instead of cn=user within them. I'll work on it.

is it possible that you have nested groups in your LDAP?
if so, try editing the nestedGroups parameter to "true" in your jaas file.

No, the groups are not nested.
